# Can this sentence be recent past?

Tags: past-participles

1. I have been doing this.
2. I have got a letter.

Can the sentence above be recent past of the past participle?

Comment: *I have been paragliding - many times when I was younger, but not since I broke my leg thirty years ago.* As a rule you'd need *context* to know whether any given usage reflects "recent past" or not. But note that in your second example ***got*** is syntactically and semantically superfluous - it means exactly the same as *I **have** a letter* (I'm in possession of a letter ***right now***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Better tell that to AOL.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It could mean "I have **received** a letter".

Comment: @Catija: I've never been too sure how AmE works in this context, but from my BrE perspective I would never say, for instance, *I have got a letter this morning*. If I didn't want to use ***received*** I'd just say *I **got** a letter...*, (or feasibly *I've **gotten** a letter...*, but I suspect that might not sound right to AmE speakers, and it wouldn't exactly be a natural choice for me either).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Both of those are fine in AmE... we (generally) jut get a bit fast and loose with "got" and tense. I think adding "just" makes it a bit easier to see the usage... "*I've just got this letter in from her today.*" As a note, **I** wouldn't use it to mean "I have received a letter"... but it is a valid interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, the present perfect continuous (sentence #1) may mean an action that happens over a period of time; it's still happening. For example:

I have continuously been doing this for 6 hours.

This tense may also indicate an action that ends just before the present. For examples:

I have been swimming. That's why my hair is wet.

I have been doing this without a break for 6 hours. That's why I am feeling tired.

As for the second sentence, its construction seems to be in the present perfect, but it's in the present simple. In fact, the idiom 'have got' used in informal English = have. However, you can rephrase your sentence as follows in the present perfect to show the action in the recent past:

I have received a letter, I have gotten a letter, or I recently got a letter.

As AlanCarmack has commented, "I have got a letter" is also the present perfect in British English.

Comment: *I have got a letter* is also the present perfect in British English.